# C++11 Passing a function with arguments to a function running in a thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I am in the process of writing a multithreaded TCP server. I am going to have one thread handle incoming socket connections, and spin off threads to handle the communication on those sockets. However, I want the thread handling socket connections to take as parameters a callback function with supporting parameters, and the compiler is complaining. Here is code to illustrate my problem:

```
template<class Function, class... Args>
void handleIncomingConnectionRequests(Function&& f, Args... args)
{
    f(args...);
}
    
void callback(int x)
{
    std::cout << x << "\n";
}
    
void main()
{
    std::thread handleIncomingConnectionsThread(handleIncomingConnectionRequests<decltype(callback)>, callback, 5);
    handleIncomingConnectionsThread.join();
}
```

When I attempt to compile this with clang on Windows, I get a fairly large compilation stack error, but the relevant issue seems to be the following:

```
error: too few arguments to function call, expected 1, have 0

f(args...);
```

Why does args appear to have no parameters? I'm clearly passing two arguments to the std::thread constructor. I have clearly done something wrong in the way I am passing the variables in, but I'm not sure how to resolve the issue.

EDIT: It was pointed out that I failed to define the second template argument. I have updated the code to read:

```
template<class Function, class... Args>
void handleIncomingConnectionRequests(Function&& f, Args... args)
{
    f(args...);
}
    
void callback(int x)
{
    std::cout << x << "\n";
}
    
void main()
{
    std::thread handleIncomingConnectionsThread(handleIncomingConnectionRequests<decltype(callback), int>, callback, 5);
    handleIncomingConnectionsThread.join();
}
```

I now get this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'invoke'
```

This error comes from the xthread file, part of the implementation of the C++ standard library for the thread include file.

Comment: Template arguments list contains only one type: `<decltype(callback)>`, missing `int` also must be provided: `<decltype(&callback),int>`. Why not to write: `std::thread th([](){ handleIncomingConnectionRequests(callback,5); });` then all arguments can be deduced by the compiler.

Comment: @rafix07 I have fixed the bug you pointed out, which leads to a different error. Using the lambda as you suggest does fix the problem, but it seems a touch unnecessary. Once fixed, the previous way should work, so from a strictly learning perspective I'd be interested in knowing why. I'd also be interested in seeing what (if any) additional overhead there is from the lambda - I'm not performance constrained in this case, but I always keep it in mind. However, thank you for the workaround to my issue!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
std::thread handleIncomingConnectionsThread(handleIncomingConnectionRequests<decltype(callback), int>, callback, 5);
```

to

```
std::thread handleIncomingConnectionsThread(handleIncomingConnectionRequests<decltype(callback)*, int>, callback, 5);
```

or

```
std::thread handleIncomingConnectionsThread(handleIncomingConnectionRequests<decltype(&callback), int>, callback, 5);
```